# Custom font in QTextDocument

Tags: css, qt, pdf, fonts, qtextdocument

I'm attempting to generate a PDF file from `QTextDocument`, which is working just fine. The issue comes when I want to use a custom font for just a specific `<p></p>` object. I tried using the standard means of `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont()` which successfully gets the font loaded into the application, but for some reason it writes all of the `QString` based variables that are added to `messageBody` in this font instead of that specified by `QTextFocument.setDefaultFont()`, or even a manually via `style={font-family:}`.

Am I doing this wrong, or overlooking something here, or is this some kind of bug?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc,argv);

        int id =  QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/BarcodeAV.ttf");
        qDebug()<< "font"<< QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id)[0];
        QString serialNumber = "ABC123";
        QString messageBody;
        messageBody += "<p style='font-size: large;'><b>Serial Number:</b> " + serialNumber + "</p>";
        messageBody += "<p style='font-size: large; font-family=\"Console\"'><b>Serial Number:</b> " + serialNumber + "</p></p>";

        QTextDocument document;
        document.setHtml(messageBody);

        QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
        printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");

        document.print(&printer);

        return 0;
}
```

---

The output PDF looks like so:

[image]

I can't wrap my head around why/how it would differentiate the base QString (messageBody) from those that are concatenated into it (serialNumber)?

---

**Edit::** No change in output after attempting to implement the style.css solution suggested below

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QFontDatabase>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc,argv);

        int id =  QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/BarcodeAV.ttf");
        qDebug()<< "font"<< QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id)[0];
        QString serialNumber = "ABC123";
        QString messageBody;
        messageBody += "<p style='font-size: large;'><b>Serial Number:</b> " + serialNumber + "</p>";
        messageBody += "<p style='font-size: large;'><b>Serial Number:</b>  <span id=\"barcode\">" + serialNumber + "</span></p>";

        QTextDocument document;
        QFile file(":/style.css");
        if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text)){
            qDebug() << "Opened CSS";
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "Failed to open CSS:" << file.errorString();
        }
        document.setDefaultStyleSheet(file.readAll());
        document.setHtml(messageBody);

        QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
        printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");

        document.print(&printer);

        return 0;
}
```

**style.css**

```
@font-face {
font-family: K-O-D-E-39 Hidden;
src: url(':/BarcodeAV.ttf');
}

#barcode{
font-family: 'K-O-D-E-39 Hidden';
font-size: larger;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to attribute attributes of each tag in a very simple way it is recommended to create a `.css` file, in this file we will use `@font-face` that loads a source through a url, in this case my source is `KODE-39 Hidden` and the file is barcode.ttf:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: K-O-D-E-39 Hidden;
  src: url('qrc:/barcode.ttf');
}
#barcode{
    font-family: 'K-O-D-E-39 Hidden';
    font-size: larger;
}
```

Then the font is added through `addApplicationFont()` and we establish through the id `barcode`. The css must also be added through the setTefaultStyleSheet method of QTextDocument:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc,argv);

    int id =  QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/barcode.ttf");
    qDebug()<< "font"<< QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id)[0];
    QString serialNumber = "ABC123";
    QString messageBody;
    messageBody += "<p style='font-size: large;'><b>Serial Number:</b> " + serialNumber + "</p>";
    messageBody += "<p style='font-size: large;'><b>Serial Number:</b>  <span id=\"barcode\">" + serialNumber + "</span></p>";

    QTextDocument document;
    QFile file(":/style.css");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text);
    document.setDefaultStyleSheet(file.readAll());
    document.setHtml(messageBody);

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");

    document.print(&printer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/48306251).

Comment: Although I'm still confused on what caused my original issue (One QString taking a certain font, another taking the default) this solved it, so thank you.

Comment: Spoke too soon, had a few other things I forgot to change while testing your solution, this does not solve my problem. Every QString value that I append to the larger QString(messageBody) is always in barcode font, but all the static text ("Serial Number") is displayed normally... really odd

Comment: @While-E You could provide a [mcve] of your problem to see what is causing it.

Comment: @While-E I just tried what you say and I do not observe the problem, maybe you do not understand what you are referring to so I can not correct it, you could show me an example of the code that generates the error and the wrong output.

Comment: I just edited my question to include the exact files I'm using. Not sure what else I can provide.

Comment: @While-E you could show a picture of what you get, you could also share your .ttf

Comment: What do you get when you run `qDebug()<<"font"<<QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id)[0];`?

Comment: I get "BarcodeAV" like expected... .ttf is not the issue, it clearly works if it's outputting barcodes. The issue is one QString being output as barcode, and the other with default font, despite never manually setting these styles, just importing it into the DB. Also, there is a picture attached to original post, that's a screenshot of the exact output. Regardless I found that if built for desktop it doesn't happen, only during cross-compile for some reason.

Comment: @While-E if when using `qDebug() << "font" << ...` you get `BarcodeAV` then you must change in the .css `K-O-D-E-39 Hidden` to `BarcodeAV`, K-O-D-E-39 Hidden is the name of the family of my font, in change his is BarcodeAV.

Comment: Yup, on desktop this allows it to work as expected. Again though, when cross-compiling, the issue is that it's applying the font globally to all QString variables that are appended to the main QString variable. Static text that is appended is fine, but QStrings being appended are show in the barcode font no matter what if it's imported into the DB....

Comment: @While-E it seems that it is a bug of its version of Qt that it uses for the cross compilation, report it.

Comment: @eyllanesc Is the `@font-face` necessary/actually working? AFAIK it's not supported on Qt, and I can get the custom font working even without that, just by using the correct font family.